# How can I stop the LogCat output from scrolling automatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to disable the scrolling in LogCat?

I am using Android Studio 0.2.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just click on a line of the logcat it will stop scrolling. You will then notice that the keys on the right become highlighted. This gives you various options among them the restart scrolling.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on a line (any line). Then it stops the auto "annoying" scroll.
(If you pass the mouse on the 4th icon, it tells you this).

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the one of line in Logcat.